# D3.JS, How can I render multiple objects in the same data binding?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data model which is an array of object with start time and end time.
Now I want to render gantt chart type cart with it.

It is easy to bind data and render a single line with it:

```
chart.data(myDataList).enter().append("line")
                              .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x})
                              .attr("y1", lineHeight)
                              .attr("x2", function(d){return d.y})
                              .attr("y2", lineHeight)
```

The data could be like

```
myDataList = [ [start time, end time], 
               [start time 2, end time 2],
               [start time 3, end time 3]]
```

Now I need to render something like this with each data item:

O-------------------O

That is addition to the line, there will be circle in both end of the line.
Circle cx data will be coming from d.x and d.y.
However, I am not quite sure how to bind the same data element in three elements.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you make the line:

```
chart.data(myDataList).enter().append("line")
                              .attr("x1", function(d){return d.x})
                              .attr("y1", lineHeight)
                              .attr("x2", function(d){return d.y})
                              .attr("y2", lineHeight)
```

now make circles

```
//make inner circle
chart.selectAll(".in").data(dataset).enter()
  .append("circle")
   .attr("class", "in")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0])
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0])
  })
  .attr("r", 2); 
  //make outer circle      
  chart.selectAll(".out").data(dataset).enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "out")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[1])
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0])
  })
  .attr("r", 2);
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/3mykrt0q/24/)

Comment: I tried this approach, but it is not working. Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pixelord/3mykrt0q/23/

if I add selectAll("circle") it render the circle. But I am not sure how to render the 2nd circle. Using selectAll("circle") over ride the position of the first set of circle.

Comment: awesome! Why didn't i think of that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First,cache the line code in a variable.

```
 var line=chart.data(myDataList).enter().append("line")
.attr("x1", function(d){return d.x}) 
.attr("y1", lineHeight) 
.attr("x2", function(d){return d.y}) 
.attr("y2", lineHeight)
```

---

Then,now using the variable,we can add circles using the same data element as

```
line.append("circle") 
.attr("cx", function(d){return d.x}) 
.attr("cy", lineHeight)
.attr("r", 4);//First circle
```

---

now,the second circle ...

```
line.append("circle") 
.attr("cx", function(d){return d.y}) 
.attr("cy", lineHeight) 
.attr("r", 4);//Second circle
```

---

Comment: This is wrong. By appending to `line` you are trying to nest the `circle` element in the `line` element. This is not permissible for SVG `line`s, which only [allow](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#LineElement) descriptive elements or animation elements as its content.